# I have a column containing datetime in format %m-%Y (e.g. 'May-2019'), but when converting this to datetime format raising error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
The code is as follows:

I identified all datetime columns and placed them under a variable as follows
datetime_columns = 
['issue_d','earliest_cr_line','last_pymnt_d','next_pymnt_d','last_credit_pull_d']

pd.to_datetime(accepted_df[datetime_columns],format='%m-%Y')



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-e6a6e4b8a6a8> in <module>
----> 1 dtd = pd.to_datetime(accepted_df[datetime_columns],format='%m-%Y')
      2 dtd = dtd.apply(pd.to_datetime)

c:\users\styli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-
```

packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc,
format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
729             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
730     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):
--> 731         result = _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors, tz)
732     elif isinstance(arg, ABCIndexClass):
733         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)

```
c:\users\styli\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _assemble_from_unit_mappings(arg, errors, tz)
    829     if len(req):
    830         required = ",".join(req)
--> 831         raise ValueError(
    832             "to assemble mappings requires at least that "
    833             f"[year, month, day] be specified: [{required}] "

ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: 
[day,month,year] is missing
```

Comment: use `%B-%Y` as parsing directive for a format like 'May-2019'. See [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that `to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified`. You only specify the year and month. So you could  also specify a day, e.g. by adding '01-' in front of each date by

```
accepted_df['datetime_column'] = '01-' + accepted_df['datetime_column'].astype(str)
pd.to_datetime(accepted_df[datetime_column],format='%d-m-%Y')
```

Comment: did you *try* this? the OP did not provide a [mre] but from the error it can be observed that *multiple* columns are passed to `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: You're right. I expected only a single column. But you could do the same for multiple columns, e.g. in a for-loop. The question wasn't that clear to me

Comment: I think the problem is that the OP has multiple columns that contain dates (with format %B-%Y) - but tries to use pd.to_datetime functionality that is intended to generate one date from multiple columns. Instead, the OP should just iteratively call pd.to_datetime(column, format='%B-%Y') for all the columns that should be converted to datetime.